# How to loop in template tag on the vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, pagination, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My code is like this :

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            @for(i=0;i<total;i++)
            <li><a href="#">{{i}}</a></li>
            @endfor
            <li>
                <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props:['total', 'data'],
        created: function(){
            console.log(this.$store.state.product.next_page);
        },
        computed:{
            next:function(){
                return this.$store.state.product.next_page
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I try the code. But it does not work.

There exist error :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "i" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

For example, variable total = 5, then it will display like this :

```
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">5</a></li>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Range `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for)

```
<li v-for="i in total">
  <a href="#">{{i}}</a>
</li>
```

Just make sure `total` is an integer and not a string. For example, instead of

```
<component-name total="5"...
```

use

```
<component-name :total="5" ...
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic

Comment: @moses dude, just ask your questions and let people answer them without being hassled

Comment: I'm sorry if I disturb you